# How can I change the screen BGcolor using JS function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple button to change the background color using JS function.
can't get it to work though...

```
<!doctype html><html>
<head>
<title>Blank Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var bg = function(){
            var color = prompt("Please enter a color" , "Color");
            return color;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Change BG" onClick="document.bgColor='bg()'">

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: bgColor is deprecated since HTML 4.0 (a long time ago), you should use `style.background` as in MartinWebb's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `''` from `'bg()'` Like so.

Please find the document.bgColor is deprecated since HTML4.0, so it's ill advised using it.

```
<script>
    function bg(){
    var color = window.prompt("Please pick color");
    return color;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" value="changeBG" onclick="document.bgColor=bg();"/>

    </body>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code when dom is ready:

```
window.onload=function() {
    var bg = function(){
        var color = prompt("Please enter a color" , "Color");
        return color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call function without single quotes and The color entered in color codes should start with '#'

```
var color = prompt("Enter the color you want on the Background???");
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

It'll work for you

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/50zj6yxj/

```
<input type="button" value="Change BG" onclick="change()">

var change = function () {
    var color = prompt("Please enter color", "#000000");
    if (color != null) {
        document.body.style.background = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to add a tad of logic test if they entered a color, add the # but i think your main problem was just getting it work as shown.